# PInnacle Studio 23 stops producing audio, no audio at all

Tags: audio, video-editing, pinnacle-studio

0

I have been using Pinnacle Studio for a while. I recently upgraded to v23 latest version. At the start everything was fine but when PS freezed due to some error (e.g. mkv file playback) the PS losts its sound in Windows 10, so no audio at all in PS.

I tried to reinstall, reset, remove, but nothing helped. The audio mixer in Windows is working correctly. I also have Pinnacle Studio v20 and installed it, but no sound either.

The Corel support couldn't help, I am struggling with this already for over a month already.

In Pinnacle Studio there is no setting to change the output audio device, no option for factory reset in this regard...

Do you have any idea?

Kind regards, Ferenc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is: you have to go to Control Panel and press Reset.
You might have to change a few things back to how you like them afterwards, of course.